# PHPMailer can't pass subject and body by $_POST

Tags: php, email, post, phpmailer

I am trying send email by PHPMailer with $_POST variables values. But it doesn't work!

```
$content = $_POST["mail_content"];
$subject = $_POST["mail_subject"];

$mail->AddBCC('my@email');
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = 'my content';

echo $mail->Subject;
$mail->send();
```

I recieved mail with content "my content" but without subject. So as you see, when I define `$mail->Body = 'my content'` it works, but when I try `$mail->Body = $content;` - it does not.

`echo $mail->Subject` returns subjects which I passed by `$_POST`.

Comment: Show your html form

Comment: Is your form sending a `POST`? Output the `$_POST` and see what you have. `var_dump($_POST);`.

Comment: There is no HTML problem because $_POST returns values which I sent.

Comment: echo $mail->Subject;
is this print the subject ? also, try to print $subject.
echo $subject;

Comment: Oh. I tested only on `echo $mail->Subject` and it pass. Problem was on $_POST['mail_content']` I using tinymce and didn't update <textarea> value on changes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the content of your $_POST. Maybe you're not getting the correct data in the post.

Try this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST); // Check what values you're getting.

echo $content = $_POST["mail_content"];
echo $subject = $_POST["mail_subject"];
```

Let me know what you get.

Comment: Oh. I tested only on `echo $mail->Subject` and it pass. Problem was on $_POST['mail_content']` I using tinymce and didn't update <textarea> value on changes... Everything works

Comment: Great! Please up vote the answer if it solved your purpose. Thanks!